# Open/Close tags based on new line (PHP Coding Pattern?)

Tags: php, syntax

While attempting to move more full stack within my company I notice with quite regularity the use of open/close tags that are not separated with non-php code. Looking at the PSR standards I can't find anything related to this. I do understand that there is no performance issue with this method, as syntax generally will not affect page performance.

### Example

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('stock.notifications') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tierprices') ?>
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
```

Would this still be considered a correct/readable pattern or when I come across patterns such as this should I look to refactor as such:

### Refactor Example

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getChildHtml('stock.notifications');
    echo $this->getChildHtml('tierprices');
    echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true);
    echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ;
?>
```

Comment: The former is often used when you are outputting stuff within a document (usually HTML, but could be anything). The latter is just outputting stuff. There is no right or proper way to do this. Just look through code that others have written, weigh the pros and cons, and then make up your own mind.

Comment: Which is more readable for you and your team (and future editors)? Which do you and the team prefer? Choose one, then run with it. Consistency is coding standards is they key.